# How to switch picture using JQuery when clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, image, slide

The script I have so far is:

```
var array = ["heil.jpeg","8bit_12.jpeg","city.jpg"];

$("#next").click(function() {
    $("img").fadeOut(function() {
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            $(this).attr('src', array[i]).fadeIn(); 
        }
    }); // end fadeOut
});
```

How can I make the index pick the next element in the array when clicking on the button `#next`?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qo5u81dk

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I nevre used it before but I hope you can understand : 
https://jsfiddle.net/qo5u81dk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched the id's "back" and "next". Also you need to calculate the index for the image-array (drawNum) correct and use it.

```
 $("#next").click(function() {
  var drawNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length));
  $("img").fadeOut(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      $(this).attr('src', array[drawNum]).fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

I modified your jsfiddle a little bit and it should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/qo5u81dk/2/

Comment: I already did that, but that's random, I want it to just select the next one and then start back again, any idea how?

Comment: I edited the jsfiddle. Now it should work the way you want it to

Comment: One more thing, how can I do the opposite using the #back ? 
here's what I did but it's not working : 
https://jsfiddle.net/qo5u81dk/8/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qo5u81dk/9/
Now it should work. You dont need a second counter since it is a static one. I dont even think that you need the for-loop, but for now i guess it works.

Answer (score 0):

the id-s in your li > div are inverted - the button labeled "NEXT" has id="back" and the reverse. In the code that you posted $("#next").click(function()  if only you replace "#next" with "#back" it works.

Comment: Actually no, "next" and "back" are just the names in HTML, the id's are corret (they were arrows and I switched them to the words next and back while posting to make it clearer).